# Conflicting Jquery files for sticky top navigation

Tags: jquery, plugins, navigation, zurb-foundation, business-catalyst

I am building a site in Business Catalyst using Foundation and a BC Gurus Template. The original template is here: http://uguru-paralax-us.businesscatalyst.com/

I'm having trouble, however because I need to insert a dropdown menu which the template did not come with. Since I have foundation running on the rest of the site I thought I would use Foundation's Sticky nav. However, I am running into an issue with conflicting jquery files. The template is using 1.9.1 and foundation 5 uses 2.1.1. I am wondering if anyone has a suggestion of how I can get a new drop down in place, either using Foundation or another third-party vendor. I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to work with the fact that I absolutely must use Jquery 1.9.1.

Thank you for any and all help!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work with jQuery 1.9.1:

https://github.com/ChrisWojcik/single-page-nav

Comment: Unfortunately this does not have the ability to do Drop downs, but thank you for the suggestion. I'm looking for a navigation bar with the ability for expansion into a drop down on certain items.